# How to insert Bulk list of dictionary to dbeaver database table using python

Tags: sql, python-3.x, list, dictionary, psycopg2

I tried some methods to load large list of dictionary data to DBeaver database table

But i have large/bulk/huge data to load so while inserting data it was not loading quickly it takes hours still my programming running

Here is the sample example of data looks like:
**Note(here i'm sharing only 10 to 20 rows of data but actually i have very huge data)**

```
 conn = psycopg2.connect(
     host= 'redshift-####-dev.)00000.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com'   ,   
    database= '*****',
    user='****',
    password='*****',
    port= '5439'
    )
    print("Succesful Connection to RedShift Dev")
cur = conn.cursor ()
df_dic =[{'case_id': 69370, 'column_name': 'subject', 'split_text': 'working', 'split_text_cnt': 1, 'load_ts': '2023-
12-15'}, {'case_id': 69370, 'column_name': 'subject', 'split_text': 'scenes', 'split_text_cnt': 1, 'load_ts': '2023-12-15'}, {'
case_id': 69370, 'column_name': 'subject', 'split_text': 'intended', 'split_text_cnt': 1, 'load_ts': '2023-12-15'}, {'case_id':
 69371, 'column_name': 'subject', 'split_text': 'redirected', 'split_text_cnt': 1, 'load_ts': '2023-12-15'}, {'case_id': 69371,
 'column_name': 'subject', 'split_text': 'ge', 'split_text_cnt': 2, 'load_ts': '2023-12-15'}, {'case_id': 69371, 'column_name':
 'subject', 'split_text': 'sensor', 'split_text_cnt': 1, 'load_ts': '2023-12-15'}, {'case_id': 69371, 'column_name': 'subject',
 'split_text': 'flush', 'split_text_cnt': 1, 'load_ts': '2023-12-15'}, {'case_id': 69371, 'column_name': 'subject', 'split_text
': 'motion', 'split_text_cnt': 1, 'load_ts': '2023-12-15'}, {'case_id': 69371, 'column_name': 'subject', 'split_text': 'led', '
split_text_cnt': 1, 'load_ts': '2023-12-15'}, {'case_id': 69371, 'column_name': 'subject', 'split_text': 'fixture', 'split_text
_cnt': 1, 'load_ts': '2023-12-15'}, {'case_id': 69371, 'column_name': 'subject', 'split_text': 'contact', 'split_text_cnt': 1,
'load_ts': '2023-12-15'}]

sql = "INSERT INTO odey.sfc_ca_sit_di (case_id,column_name,split_text,split_text_cnt,load_ts) VALUES (%(case_id)s,%(column_name)s,%(case_subject)s,%(Case_Subject_Split_Count)s,%(load_date)s)"
cur.executemany(sql, df_dic)
conn.commit()
```

This is how i'm trying to insert data but it's taking too much time

Can anyone please suggest how can i insert very quickly data to database

even i tired in dataframe to sql but no use

Please read question carefully before answering!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgresql + psycopg: Bulk Insert large data with POSTGRESQL function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74095783/postgresql-psycopg-bulk-insert-large-data-with-postgresql-function-call)

Comment: Also, the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8134602/5320906) may be useful.

Comment: `executemany` is known to be slow. The methods here [Fast execution helpers](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers) will speed things up. See my answer using `execute_batch` at the link @snakecharmerb posted. The fastest way to bulk load data is to use the `COPY` methods here [psycopg2 COPY](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from). This assumes you can get the data formatted correctly and in a file-like object.